# Configuring Categorizations With Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, categorization

I want to be able to assign categories to my user's (up to 2, allow for 1). I want any posts by this user to be assigned only one category from the same list of categories (which are referred to as profession(s) for my app).

Currently, I have configured it so that I can assign 1 to each, with simple belongs_to and has_many associations between the user, post, and profession models. This works fine for the post, because it only requires 1 profession assignment, but for the user it is limiting the ability for 2.

The view for the user has two drop-down lists, populated by the items in the profession. I can select two different professions, but only one retains the value for the profession, where I would like it to keep both or only accept one if only one has been selected. My major limitation is that in the user database, there is only one profession column that refers to the profession_id. I can't duplicate the profession column, so how do I set it up so that a second profession field can be added?

Or, how should I change my database design and models to accomplish this?

user.rb:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      attr_accessible :email, 
                      :password, 
                      :password_confirmation,
                      :remember_me, 
                      :first_name, 
                      :last_name, 
                      :profile_name, 
                      :full_bio, 
                      :mini_bio,
                      :current_password,
                      :photo,
                      :profession_id

      attr_accessor :current_password

      validates :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name, presence: true

      validates :profile_name, uniqueness: true,
                               format: {
                                  with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/
                               }

      has_many :posts
      belongs_to :profession

      has_attached_file :photo,
                        :default_url => 'default.png'


      def full_name
        first_name + " " + last_name
      end
    end
```

post.rb:

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :content, :name, :user_id, :profession_id
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :profession

      validates :content, presence: true,
                  length: { minimum: 2 }

      validates :name, presence: true,
                  length: { minimum: 2 }

      validates :user_id, presence: true

    end
```

profession.rb:

```
    class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name

      has_many :posts
      has_many :users
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a `has_many :through` association for your Users and Professions may work best. With an additional model of something like "Specialty", you can model this relationship as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :specialties
  has_many :professions, :through => :specialties
end

class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :specialties
  has_many :users, :through => :specialties
end

class Specialty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profession
end
```

You can then use the [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) in your view to accept the professions associated with that user.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am still confused, however, on how I would attach multiple professions to a user. This is my major trouble.

Comment: As a secondary question (I'm still getting a hang of Rails), why is this model arrangement different and better than the way I have it currently?